# Does the FLRW metric account for the decrease in density for an expanding universe?

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, universe

In other words, is it assumed that the fluid density is constant after expansion and through the time development of an expanding universe?

Answer (score 1):

For what I remember I would say that FRW metric certainly account for that; in fact a constant energy density in an expanding universe should mean that there is energy production, but from where exactly? I can cite the Hubble parameter equation
\begin{equation*}
\left(H(t)\right)^2
=
\left(H(t_r)\right)^2
\left(
\frac{\Omega_{\text{mat}}(t_r)}{s^3(t,t_r)}
+\frac{\Omega_{\text{rad}}(t_r)}{s^4(t,t_r)}
+\Omega_\Lambda(t_r)
+\frac{\Omega_\alpha(t_r)}{s^2(t,t_r)}
\right)
\end{equation*}
where you have an emission time $t$, a receiving time $t_r$ and a normalized scale factor $s(t,t_r)\doteq\tilde{S}(t)/\tilde{S}(t_r)$ (where $\tilde{S}$ represents $S/\sqrt{|K|}$). You can recognize the presence of

- Matter density parameter, decreasing with $s^3$, representing exactly the tridimensional volume change
- Radiation density parameter, that goes with $s^4$, why? because the expansion redshifts the radiation!
- Vacuum density parameter, just constant because the vacuum has an unaltered nature
- Curvature density parameter, a really esotic and wild animal!

Considering also that $H(t)\approx\partial_t \tilde{S}(t)/\tilde{S}(t)$ this means that the universe expands changing scale factor due to the fact that energy density changes.

I hope it was helpful and without big errors.